# Apple accessing Samba Share on Linux The operation can't be completed because the original item can't be found

Tags: unix, sharing, smb

I'm trying to connect to samba shares on a debian machine in the same network from a Mac running Ventura 13.4.1. It all works perfectly fine if I do CMD+K, and input the credentials there (like smb://user@serverIP) However, trying to connect via double-clicking the share under "Network" on Mac results in the error "The operation can't be completed because the original item can't be found". I installed avahi-deamon after which the server started to be discovered by mac automatically but I can't connect to it double-clicking the auto discovered share.

I'm absolutely out of ideas.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly it started working the next day without me changing anything at all. I'm very surprised to say the least. Actually, I'm shocked. I guess, the takeaway is that if you want your server to get auto discovered and displayed under "Network" on OSX, you need to install the package "avahi-daemon" and then wait...? No other configuration was needed in my case.